# Is crazy craft and orespawn mod the same thing in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

Is crazy craft and orespawn mod the same thing in minecraft? My friend told me about crazy craft, but are they the same thing?

http://www.orespawn.com/

http://voidswrath.com/newwp/crazy-craft/

Comment: Could you add links to the mod pages on your post? Can you give us a ruff impression what you want the mod(s) to do?

Comment: orespawnmod is pure craziness, with new mobs, but so is crazycraft!crazycraft just has more i think.

Comment: im not sure for sure, but im pretty sure.

Comment: modpacks often share mods. I can't look into it right now but a simple way to find out whats different is to load up each client and compare list of mods.

Answer (score 1):

No they are not the same thing. Crazy Craft is a whole bunch of mods that do all sorts of crazy things. OreSpawn is a single mod used as the "base" of Crazy Craft because of the number of awesome mobs that it has (along with other things). In other words, they took the OreSpawn mod, threw about 50 mods  on top, and called it Crazy Craft. This is good. This is what OreSpawn is for.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, they are essentially the same, except for some crafting differences

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on these differences?

Answer (score -5):

No there different things crazy craft is crazy not normal then minecraft